# SQL query in SQLite doesn't terminate

Tags: sql, database, performance, sqlite, inner-join

I have a table in an **SQLite** database in the following form:

| Timestamp | fst_field | ... | fifth_field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | X | ... | ... |
| 10003 | Y | ... | ... |
| 10005 | Z | ... | ... |
| 10020 | W | ... | ... |

It doesn't have any primary key and all the fields are of type text except for the Timestamp (int)

The following query:

```
SELECT s.Timestamp, s.fst_field , ..., s.fifth_field, p.Timestamp, p.fst_field, ..., p.fifth_field
FROM table s JOIN table p ON s.Timestamp < p.Timestamp AND p.Timestamp - s.Timestamp < 10
```

should output every row next to all its following rows within a threshold (here 10).

The output looks like the following:

| s.Timestamp | s.fst_field | ... | s.fifth_field | p.Timestamp | p.fst_field | ... | p.fifth_field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | X | ... | ... | 10003 | Y | ... |  |
| 10001 | X | ... | ... | 10005 | Z | ... |  |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |  |  |  |

The query works for tables with 4000 rows. However, when I try it with tables with 22 million rows (1,4 GB file) it keeps running for days without ever stopping. I tried adding indexes, even to every attribute, to make the query faster but that didn't help. I ran the code both on Linux and Windows.

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: This is probably because you are not using a JOIN but a CROSS JOIN (implicit when you put the comma between table names), which is not a very good statement performance wise. please dscribe your tables definition and what you want to have as a result, or add an explicit join clause in the query

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  There might be a much simpler method.

Comment: Yes even with using  JOIN it still doesn't terminate. I hope the structure of the initial table and the result are now clear

Comment: 22 million rows is big enough to optimize your SQL query. Here `JOIN` on `p.Timestamp - s.Timestamp < 10` seems to be consuming. you may add an index on `Timestamp` and check the difference on result (BI, Excel, programming language, etc...)

Comment: I already tried adding an index on Timestamp, that accelerated the query for a table of 4000 rows but didn't notice any difference with larger tables as the query never terminates.
Could the problem be specific to SQLite? In the documentation, it is mentioned that they should scale to TB large databases but it is not the case for this query.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. (Constraints, indexes & plans are critical.) Please research before considering posting. That includes basics of SQL optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [ask]

Comment: Adding indexes to every attribute is pointless. Maybe this will even confuse the query optimizer when deciding on which indexes to use when running the query. Run an execution plan and see. What could definitely help is filtering data at the source. If for example you know that the timestamps should be within a certain range, then you could apply filtering with a WHERE clause. Possibly other fields could be filtered too, but we don't have any insight into your system. The point is to avoid scanning 22 million rows but only a limited subset of that data.

Comment: If the goal is to compare two subsets of data a CTE may be of help in this scenario - [here](https://www.guru99.com/sqlite-query.html#12) is an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the amount of time needed for the program to terminate grows exponentially. Trying out smaller datasets worked fine. Although it is not possible to filter the input, one could think of a way to split it somehow. Adding indexes improved the results by far but still, it isn't a magical solution for all inputs.